# Regular expression for matching 5 criteria

Tags: regex

I have a text file containing a large number of random lines that looks like this :

- 654bdfueogp48g4e
- 1852rhogkent4
- gihngpenitg
- 12reokgr8o5gLE
- FGJTfhds899
- 45954efreikLF
- 598Gfkoggge555yN
- Gdogrkrngo

I'm looking to create a regular expression that matches the following criteria :

A sequence of 6 to 11 alphabetical letters.
This sequence can either stand **alone** on a line, or :

- Be preceded **only** by 1 to 6 digits at the beginning of the line.
- Be followed **only** by 1 to 6 digits at the end of the line.
- **The sequence should **NOT** be both preceded **AND** followed by digits.**

After several unsuccessful attempts, I've created a regex that comes close to the criteria I mentioned above :

> (?<=^\d{0,6})\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6}$)

The issue here is that my last criteria (in bold) is not being taken into account, and I have no idea how to solve this.

Is there a regex expert who could help me please ?

Comment: Like this? `^(?:\d{0,6}\p{L}{6,11}|\p{L}{6,11}\d{0,6})$` https://regex101.com/r/DJRmqS/1 Or only the match for the letters `(?:(?<=^\d{0,6})\p{L}{6,11}$|^\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6})$)` https://regex101.com/r/gxrEaV/1

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to specify a fundamental point : it should capture only alphabetical characters, without the digits before or after.

Comment: Yes like the second pattern in the comment https://regex101.com/r/gxrEaV/1

Comment: If the regex engine supports `\K` (discard all characters matched so far from the match that will be returned), which includes Perl, PCRE, Python's alternate regex engine, Ruby..., you could use `^\d{0,6}\K\p{L}{6,11}$|^\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6}$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MddvqA/1). (Much of expression taken from @Thefourthbird's answer.)

Comment: Related: [Regex: an optional substring that can appear in one of two places, but not both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61868445/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either assert 0-6 digits to the left from the start of the string denoted by `\d{0,6}` followed by 6-11 letters, or the other way around asserting 0-6 digits to the end of the string.

This will then also match a sequence of 6 to 11 alphabetical letters alone on a line:

```
(?<=^\d{0,6})\p{L}{6,11}$|^\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fwJdf5/1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this regex does not match the following criteria : Be followed only by 1 to 6 digits at the end of the line.

Comment: @Jpie Then you can change the quantifier like this `(?:(?<=^\d{1,6})\p{L}{6,11}$|^\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{1,6})$)` https://regex101.com/r/BUZQeI/1

Comment: So, no possibility of having this regex matching all the critera at once ?

Comment: @Jpie It's hard to implement the "not both" logic in a single pattern, because regular expressions don't have a way to save the state between the two criteria.

Comment: @Jpie Do you want multiple matches in a single line? Because `A sequence of 6 to 11 alphabetical letters.` and `Be preceded only by 1 to 6 digits at the beginning of the line` or at the end of the line is `(?<=^\d{0,6})\p{L}{6,11}$|^\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6})$` https://regex101.com/r/S3vKAh/1

Comment: What I especially wanted was to be able to match alphabetical letters followed by 1 to 6 digits but it only works for alphabetical letters preceded by 1 to 6 digits.

Comment: @Jpie It would be easier to update your question, and clearly state the expected matches. This matches the letters followed by 1-6 digits `(?<!\p{L})\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{1,6}(?!\d))` https://regex101.com/r/F2W2la/1

Comment: @Jpie Or your own pattern setup `(?<=(?<!\d)\d{1,6})\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{1,6}(?!\d))` https://regex101.com/r/Olu9Lf/1 Or with 0-6 digits `(?<=(?<!\d)\d{0,6})\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6}(?!\d))`  https://regex101.com/r/vtT1DB/1

Comment: I mean the "not both" logic.

Comment: @Jpie Please update the question with clear examples what should and what should not match and also if you want multiple matches in a single string. Also, what is the tool or language?

Comment: It's just not possible in a single pattern to match one single alphabetical string if it is both preceded and followed by numbers.

Comment: @Jpie It is possible, just look at the first pattern in my second last comment. But WHAT you want to match is not really clear to me at least. That is why you should update your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right about that, thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, it was early in the morning on my mobile phone. Not the best platform to do this :-)

Comment: The qualifier "mobile" is not needed considering the difficulty of doing that from a land line.

Comment: @The fourth bird You've found the right regex !!! Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative lookahead (anchored to start) for a digit at both ends:

```
^(?!\d.*\d$)\d{0,6}(\p{L}{6,11})\d{0,6}$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/g9hDRv9a9JLQLA).

The letters are captured as group 1.

Comment: Nice to avoid use of a relatively expensive variable-length lookbehind!

Comment: @CarySwoveland It is, but the OP states in the comments `it should capture only alphabetical characters, without the digits before or after` So this is basically the same as my very first pattern in the comments without any lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am predominantly a PHP developer, I prefer to implement regex patterns that are PCRE2 compliant.  PHP's regex engine is going to choke on a pattern that uses a variable length lookbehind.

I have designed a pattern which does not use a variable length lookbehind AND doesn't need to repeat the subpattern in the middle of the pattern for the sake of validating the leading/trailing subpatterns.

[PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/TjIjk)

```
/
^                #start of string
(\d{1,6})?       #capture #1: 1 or more digits
\p{L}{6,11}      #match 6 to 11 letters without 3 consecutively repeated letters
(?(1)|\d{0,6})   #if capture #1 was true, match nothing, else match optional digits
$                #end of string
/xu              #x: ignore whitespaces in pattern, u: process as multibyte characters
```

If you, per say, [want to implement more logic in the middle of your pattern to disqualify strings which have 3 consecutive repetitions of the same letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77876363/2943403), then you don't need to manually duplicate the whole middle subpattern on either side of the alternation/pipe.

```
/^(\d{1,6})?(?!.*(\p{L})\2\2)\p{L}{6,11}(?(1)|\d{0,6})$/u
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- use a negated lookahead
```

Here is the adjusted pattern to only return the letters from qualifying inputs via `preg_match()`: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/aOs4n).

The "magic" is in the `(?(1)|\d{0,6})` conditional expression.

This reads as:

- if the first capture group was a match, then match the subpattern before the pipe (nothing, in this case);
- else match the subpattern after the pipe (a zero to six number string, in this case).

My observations are that between the two PHP-compliant patterns, my answer is more concise and requires fewer steps by the regex engine versus Bohemian's answer to match the same strings from the sample set.