# Regular expression to match very specific criteria

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a regular expression `(?<=^\d{0,6})(?!.*(\p{L})\1\1)\p{L}{6,11}$|^(?!.*(\p{L})\2\2)\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6}$)` that matches these criteria :

A sequence of 6 to 11 alphabetical letters. This sequence can either stand **alone**, or :

- Be preceded **only** by 1 to 6 digits at the beginning of the line.
- Be followed **only** by 1 to 6 digits at the end of the line.
- Sequence should **NOT** be both preceded **AND** followed by digits.
- Sequence of 6 to 11 alphabetic letters should **NOT** contain more than 2 repeated letters, regardless of whether there are any digit(s) before or after.

I want to add a last criteria : digits before or after sequence of 6 to 11 alphabetic letters should **NOT** contain more than 4 repeated digits

Here are a sample of the inputs from my txt file :

- **00000**48hghtrff7
- 295gdfinnnn548
- GJJfdDDDuhuBBB59
- 654bdfueogp48g4e
- 1852rhogkent4
- gihngpenitg
- 12reokgr8o5gLE
- FGJTfhds899
- 45954efreikLF
- 598Gfkoggge555yN
- Gdogrkrngo
- fmidjkydf14**22222**

I modified the regex by adding these assertion `(?!([0-9])\1{3})` `(?!([0-9])\2{3})` but this doesn't seem to do anything since the lines starting or ending with at least 5 times the same consecutive digits are still there.

```
(?<=^\d{0,6})(?!([0-9])\1{3})(?!.*(\p{L})\1\1)\p{L}{6,11}$|^(?!([0-9])\2{3})(?!.*(\p{L})\2\2)\p{L}{6,11}(?=\d{0,6}$)
```

How can achieve this ?

Comment: Haven't you asked the similar question yesterday and were adviced to use some programming language instead? Yes, you can do it with a regular expression and no, you won't understand it within a couple of months. Additionally, which programming language do you use?

Comment: What language are you using? Most regexp engines don't allow variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: @Jan It was 4 days ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862554/regular-expression-for-matching-5-criteria - unless there's another question that was asked and deleted.

Comment: @Barmar: Fiddled with `(DEFINE)` which made it far more readable: https://regex101.com/r/6bD5kw/1 - only because it's possible :-)

Comment: So not more than 2 is actually not 3 right? Try `(?<=^\d{0,6}(?!\p{L}*(\p{L})\1\1))(?<!^\d*\2{4}(\d)\d*)\p{L}{6,11}$|^(?!.*(\p{L})\3\3)\p{L}{6,11}(?!\d*(\d)\4{4})(?=\d{0,6}$)` https://regex101.com/r/BcFB8U/1

Comment: It's OK to use this as learning exercise (I've seen your earlier versions of this question), but in practice you may find it preferable to break this into several steps, the last being merely `\p{L}+`. Two advantages are that it makes testing a lot easier and it facilitates possible future changes in requirements.

Comment: @Jpie Did that regex work out for you?